# Does inflater require Activity's context?

Tags: android, android-layout

I sometimes inject link to `LayoutInflater` by Dagger, and produce it in module from Application context like this: `LayoutInflater.from(application);`. It reduces lines of code.

But colleges tell me that it is wrong way, and it has to be given from Activity context by `LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);`

Is it true? Does behaviour of layout inflater depend on type of context?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is true. There's a big difference considering styles.

The `LayoutInflater` creates the views by calling their constructors. There it passes the context you passed to it. So if you use the application context instead of an activity context you might lack some information.

It's the same issue like using application context for creating views directly. Activities may define different styles and their contexts wrap these information.

Taking into consideration how you could get it, there's not a big difference. Internally [`LayoutInflater.cloneInContext(Context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#cloneInContext(android.content.Context)) is called to apply different context configurations.

> Create a copy of the existing `LayoutInflater` object, with the copy pointing to a different `Context` than the original. This is used by `ContextThemeWrapper` to create a new `LayoutInflater` to go along with the new `Context` theme.

With the application context you don't get this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand things correctly, in case of using application context for creating LayoutInflater you have a chance to loose your Theme settings. See here for [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118251/theme-style-is-not-applied-when-inflater-used-with-applicationcontext) details.

**UPDATED**

From [source code of layout inflater](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#LayoutInflater.createView%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Candroid.util.AttributeSet%29):

```
Object[] args = mConstructorArgs;
args[1] = attrs;

constructor.setAccessible(true);
final View view = constructor.newInstance(args);
if (view instanceof ViewStub) {
    // Use the same context when inflating ViewStub later.
    final ViewStub viewStub = (ViewStub) view;
    viewStub.setLayoutInflater(cloneInContext((Context) args[0]));
}
return view;
```

As you can see, your context (in your case application context) passes in constructions of View. It means that scope of your view will be application, not activity.

Answer (score 1):

If we Application context means, the inflater instance exist throughout the application until the app is killed. In other case, if we use activity context the inflater instance will be removed once activity is destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `getApplicationContext()` when you know you need a Context for something that may live longer than any other likely Context you have at your disposal like `services` .

So It is best practice to use `activity context` when you dont need your object that will hold for long time or to global scale.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But question was about LayoutInflater. Will I look any difference in UI if I use LayoutInflater produced from the Application context?

Comment: No you wont. So use activity context for better memory management.