# Wrong button's color in view added by WindowManager

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I add overlay layout via WindowManager to the screen and I have button there with `android:theme` parameter:

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.button_view, null);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);
windowManager.addView(view, params)
```

button_view

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <Button
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The color `color_accent` is blue and on emulators with api 23-25 the color of button is also blue.

But on emulator with api 16 it's light gray and on on emulator with api 22 it is red.

How can I fix that?

When I add this button with this theme to the activity's layout, it works.

Comment: Show how you have inflated the `view`.

Comment: @azizbekian edited

Comment: While inflating the `View`, your are passing a `this` context. What is the theme of that activity?

Comment: Instead of `android:theme` perform `app:theme`. I think this will resolve the issue.

Comment: @azizbekian No, it's Service's context

Comment: Try removing PixelFormat in WindowManager.LayoutParams.

Comment: @cyanide And what format I should put there after removing PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT?

Comment: @azizbekian `app:theme` does not help

Comment: Maybe PixelFormat.OPAQUE or PixelFormat.RGBA_8888.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Theme/Style is not applied when inflater used with ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118251/theme-style-is-not-applied-when-inflater-used-with-applicationcontext)